# Blazor - OnAfterRenderAsync called again even previous is not finished

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I run into problem with multiple times called *OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)* even previous run of the same method in same component is not finished.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        _jsModule = await JsRuntime.LoadJSModule(this);
        await _jsModule!.InvokeVoidAsync("doLogic");
    }

    await _jsModule!.InvokeVoidAsync("doSomethingElse");
}
```

What's problem:

1. On OnAfterRenderAsync runs first time with parameter firstRender = true;
2. It goes inside first condition.
3. I run StateHasChanged in parent component.
4. On AfterRenderAsync is called second time with paremeter firstRender = false, even first run is still running and it's inside first condition.
5. Second run skipped first condition and goes directly to logic after, but _jsModule is still null here. So it fails.

How this situation should be handled correctly? I tried use Semaphore, and then it works fine. But I think that this situation should be handled somehow by Blazor itself?
I found this problem with one component till now, because I run StateHasChanged in very short period of time.

I can imagine that it can happens also in other components and should be solved generally. Do you have some ideas or do I miss something?

Comment: Why don't you let `doLogic` execute `doSomethingElse` when it is done? The issue is a race condition that cannot be met. They are in different scopes and the one will not wait for the other.

Comment: In `doLogic`, there is some init logic which should run only once. Yes, I can do that, that in first run `doLogic` will execute `doSomethingElse`. Anyway in other runs I need to run only `doSomethingElse` because parameters have been changed, but in my case JsModule is still not loaded and init logic is not finished.

Answer (score 0):

`OnAfterRender{Async}` is a UI Event.  It's not an intrinsic part of the lifecycle.  It's called after component renders.  When it gets invokes is dependant on load on the `SynchronisationContext` running the Blazor UI context.

You can assign the load method to a global variable and then await it like this:

```cs
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private Task<bool> _moduleLoad = Task.FromResult(true);

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Use this if you want to bail out if OnAfterRenderAsync is already running
        if (!_moduleLoad.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRenderAsync bailed out");
            return;
        }

        if (firstRender)
            _moduleLoad = DoSomethingSlow();

        var x = await _moduleLoad;
        var y = await DoSomethingElse();
    }

    private async Task<bool> DoSomethingSlow()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingSlow started");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingSlow completed");
        return true;
    }

    private async Task<bool> DoSomethingElse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse started");
        await Task.Delay(10);
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse completed");
        return true;
    }
}
```

What you get is:

```
DoSomethingSlow started
OnAfterRenderAsync bailed out
DoSomethingSlow completed
DoSomethingElse started
DoSomethingElse completed
```

Comment: It will help, if I don't need to run DoSomethingElse in second run but I do, because parameters have been changed and logic in DoSomethingElse in dependent on parameters value.

Comment: So don't use the `if (!_moduleLoad.IsCompleted)` code block.  I added it to demonstrate how to handle both situations.  It will then run as you want.  Note that the code in `DoSomethingElse` will use the current state of the component when it's run.

Comment: _"logic in DoSomethingElse in dependent on parameters"_ then run it in OnParametersSet().

Comment: @HH - I'm assuming the OP is doing JS stuff: we'll find out.